# Integrate Elasticsearch in Spring Boot Project

Tags: spring, maven, elasticsearch

I have to integrate Elasticsearch (5.1.1) in a Spring Boot Web Application. I've discovered all of the Manuals and Documentations but I all examples are not working for me.

It starts with the pom.xml dependencies...

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repositories")
public class ElasticsearchConfig {

@Bean
public Client client() {
    TransportClient client = new TransportClient();
    TransportAddress address = new InetSocketTransportAddress(environment.getProperty("elasticsearch.host"), Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("elasticsearch.port")));
    client.addTransportAddress(address);    
    return client;
}
```

In my JavaConfig it can not resolve any Type like TransportClient..Can someone help me please?

**UPDATE**

I've updated the version from spring-boot 1.4.1.RELEASE to 1.4.2.RELEASE and it works now!

Comment: Which version of spring-boot and spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch are you using? The latest  supported ES version is 2.4.0.

Comment: For spring-boot I am using **1.4.1.RELEASE** and the spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch version is managed from spring-boot above.

The supported ES version doesn't matter for my problem ... I think ... my Problem is that I can not import the correct Things in my Config File.

Comment: could you share your pom dependencies in the question to get the details of libs used please

Comment: Ok, I've just updated Spring-Boot to 1.4.2.RELEASE and the imports are getting to work again!