# ElasticSearch 5.1.1 support on Spring Boot 1.4.1

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot

I'm trying to connect to ES cluster version 5.1.1 on AWS and I'm getting error

java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format, got (48,54,54,50)

The application is built using spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch. The same app works with ES 2.4 version so I'm thinking this is version compatibility issue. Is there a upgrade or support for ES 5.1.1 in Spring Boot and Spring Data ?

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058848/integrate-elasticsearch-in-spring-boot-project

Answer (score 0):

As of today the currently supported elastic search version is elaseticsearch 2.x(*<5) if you're using the available stable release of spring data elastic search(2.x) as you can see in this [compatibility matrix link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/wiki/Spring-Data-Elasticsearch---Spring-Boot---version-matrix).

I believe that support for elastic search 5.x is planned for spring data elasticsearch(need confirmation) [3.x that is currently M1](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-elasticsearch/) but then I think you need to bump also your spring boot version.